# How to I prevent widgets in a QGridLayout from overlapping?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a `QGridLayout` that has a number of widgets in six rows.  Rows 1, 3 and 5 contain a `QLabel`, a `QLineEdit` and a `QPushButton` that opens up a file selection dialog.  Rows 2, 4, and 6 contain a `QLabel` that is used to present validation errors to the user.  The errors are hidden in the image below.

When the window is able to take up as much space as it likes, this issue does not appear.  But when I restrict the size of the window at all, the elements in this list look like this:

[image: QGridLayout with vertically restricted elements]

So my question is, how do I ensure that all qwidgets in the QGridLayout can take up as much space as they need?

**EDIT:**
Following @Avaris' suggestion, I tried calling `setMinimumSize()` for each widget in the `QGridLayout` (all 6 rows), and the visible elements look much better (thanks, @Avaris!).  Yet now when I cause a validation error, the error itself (a red `QLabel`) is laid over the other widgets.  Can I force the QGridLayout to not overlap?

Here's what it looks like now:
[image]

Comment: Did you set the minimum size for those widgets to something small?

Comment: @Avaris, I tried your suggestion and it works well for the visible elements.  Yet the other rows (which contain a hidden `QLabel`) is now displayed on top of the other elements.  Can I force them all to be in line?  Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you to set minimum size :). I was asking if you *did* set anything before. If you didn't set any size for your widgets they shouldn't get that small. Can you post some code?

Comment: @Avaris, Actually, setting a minimum size _was_ the correct solution ... it's apparently been a longstanding issue with the QGridLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching around for a solution, I found [something in the TrollTech archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20051112104527/http://lists.trolltech.com:80/qt-interest/1998-11/thread00370-0.html) that supported @Avaris's idea about setting the minimum size of the widget.  The post suggests setting a minimum size for each widget in the QGridLayout.

My implementation looks like this as I loop through all elements to be added to my QGridLayout:

```
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
hint = widget.sizeHint()
if hint.isValid():
    widget.setMinimumSize(hint)
```

The validity of a hint varies on the layout used, but widget sizehints always seem to be valid when I use a QGridLayout.

Comment: Uh-oh. The link has died, do you happen to remember what it was about?

Comment: Ah, so sorry, I don't remember the details!  Since most of the TrollTech archives' code samples were in C++, I suspect that it was very similar to the python code example I provided above.